# Foreign key in User table getting saved but immediately rolling back

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have a very strange issue that I've been banging my head on for days now.

What's **SUPPOSED** to happen: The user hits a URL/view which has some logic to make a new object in my Payments table, which is then immediately saved as a foreign key to my User table. The view's HttpResponse is returned and the foreign key is preserved (of course).

What **ACTUALLY** happens: The foreign key saves with no issues, but is erased as soon as the function execution is over (specifically, when the HttpResponse is returned from the view). The User table's foreign key becomes "NULL" in the MySQL database.

--

What are some potential causes of this? It looks like there is some type of rollback that is being triggered here. I've had some ideas (like checking the custom middleware), but those haven't yielded any results.

Some other caveats:

- I've tried updating a text field in the same transaction, and that's getting rolled back after the HttpResponse as well. So we know it's not just the foreign key that's getting undone.
- When I go into the django shell and replicate the view's logic (create a new Payment object then save it as a foreign key to the  User table), it permanently saves the foreign key without any issues or rollbacks! So we know it's not something that's directly related to the function's logic.
- I tried hitting the URL through my browser while logged in to my website with a superuser account but that didn't change anything. I *think* this means it can't be a permissions issue, but not completely sure.

Any thoughts/ideas are greatly appreciated :(

UPDATE: here is a shortened recreation of my code:

```
class CapturePayment(View):
  def get(self, request, auth_id, user_id):
    pmt = Payment.objects.get(id=auth_id) // get the payment object that was successfully made in prev function
    usr = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    usr.payment_fk = pmt  // also have tried "usr.payment_fk_id = pmt.id"
    usr.save()

    // here I do another lookup on the same user to see if this object saved.
    check_usr = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    logger.info(check_usr.payment_fk) // shows up in the log with the correct payment object

    // HttpResponse returns, but upon checking MySQL database the foreign key is replaced with "NULL" again
    return HttpResponse(something)
```

Comment: Are you using transactions? if you are not sure (not your code) you should check, this is a typical ATOMIC behavior.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Sorry, but have to ask.. are you committing the transaction? If you don't commit, it'll be rolled back automatically.

Comment: @Arth - Yes, I am calling the .save() method on the User object after setting the foreign key. When I am still within the function (before it returns HttpResponses), I can look up that user again and show the Payment object is saved as a foreign key to that User object.

Comment: @jball037, Sounds good.. but that is not the same as committing the transaction.

Comment: @petkostas - Had to dig around a bit, but no we're not using Atomic/transactions for this table, at least as far ask I can see. There are no atomic decorators on the model and I couldn't find any context manager's within "atomic" in them... Is there anywhere I should be looking? So far no indication that we're using transactions.

Comment: You need to show the code of the view, and also show how/where you are verifying that your changes are being "rolled back". This probably isn't actually transactions being rolled back, in fact.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I don't actually know that they are being rolled back, just said it was my best guess. Can you suggest any likely alternatives as to what this might be? I will add some code now...

Comment: @DanielRoseman - just added the code sample

Comment: And where are you verifying that the changes didn't take? Directly in the MySQL shell, or where?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've also checked the MySQL shell just before the HttpResponse was called (I put a time.sleep(10) before it to check), and verified that the foreign key showed up there as well. Same issue: it's there before HttpResponse, and gone after.

Comment: That is very weird, I've never heard of anything like this before. Can you show the contents of the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting?

Comment: Just the defaults and a few custom middlewares that basically just set cookies - nothing that affects either of the tables :/

Answer (score 0):

Commit the transaction when you are done!

Check that AUTOCOMMIT is not set to FALSE.. according to the [link in the comments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/)..

> You can totally disable Django’s transaction management for a given database by setting AUTOCOMMIT to False in its configuration. If you do this, Django won’t enable autocommit, and won’t perform any commits. You’ll get the regular behavior of the underlying database library.

You may need to check this in your MySQL as well.

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE variable_name = 'autocommit';
```

Comment: I can the SQL command you gave and automcommit is "ON" (and the django version I'm using is 1.6.5)

Comment: @jball037 Cool, what about in the django config for your database?

Comment: Hm not positive if I'm looking in the right place but there's a file called ".../mysql/base.py" within the setups folder that has: "atomic_transactions = False" under the class "class DatabaseFeatures(BaseDatabaseFeatures):"

Comment: @jball037 call `get_autocommit()` to check it.

Comment: @jball037 Ah, then I suggest you read through the rest of the link to try and find an answer.. I'm not sure I can help you. Sorry. I'm fairly sure it has something to do with transactions however.